# Bounding mutual information for almost product states

Tags: quantum-information, entropy

Fix some natural number $n$ and a small $\epsilon>0$,

let us denote by $S_{n,k}^\epsilon$ the set of bipartite states on $M_n\otimes M_k$ that are $\epsilon$ close to some product state in some given norm: $S_{n,k}^\epsilon = \{\rho \in M_n\otimes M_k ~;~ \exists \sigma_1\in M_n, \sigma_2 \in M_k: \lVert \rho - \sigma_1\otimes \sigma_2 \rVert < \epsilon\}$.

Define the mutual information between the first and second system for a state $\rho\in M_n\otimes M_k$ by $I(\rho^A : \rho^B) = S(\rho^A) + S(\rho^B) - S(\rho)$. I'm interested in the maximal mutual information that is achievable for states $\epsilon$ close to seperable/product states:
$$
M(n,\epsilon) = \sup_k\max{\{I(\rho^A: \rho^B) ~;~ \rho \in S_{n,k}^\epsilon\}}
$$

Can this quantity $M(n,\epsilon)$ be easily bounded in terms of $n$ and $\epsilon$?. I know that for a fixed value of $k$, it is possible to find a bound using the continuity of entropy and mutual information, but this introduces a dependence on $k$ that blows up as $k\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Upper bounds or lower bounds?  Can you be more specific on the bound you have (and how you get it), so it is clear what to improve upon (or the optimality of what to show)?

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is small the state is close to separating. This means the mutual information should be small, so I am looking for an upper bound that can be expressed in terms of $\epsilon$ and possibly $n$ that makes this intuition exact.